# Why does the inverse limit have two names?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Why do we call the inverse limit a projective limit? If I've understood correctly there are two name for the same object so I would glad to know if there is a simple explanation of this.

Comment: Projective limits are also called inverse limits, yes. Is there a rule against having many names for the same thing?

Comment: No but sometimes could be a motivation

Comment: I think "projective" is motivated by the fact that the inverse limit of an inverse system has canonical projections to all the members of that system. The idea is reinforced by the fact that in many of the classical instances, these projections are surjective. And they are, in any case, restrictions of the projection maps of a direct product.

Comment: To head off a likely future question: Inverse / projective limits are sometimes just called limits. In such contexts, direct limits would be called colimits.  (My computer's spell-checker doesn't recognize "colimit" as a word; worse, TeX thinks it should be hyphenated as "col-imit".)

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think that would do well as an answer- please consider recording it as such below.

Comment: We use the same term to describe multiple concepts (e.g., “normal”). It only seems fair that from time to time we use multiple terms to describe the same concept...